# Undefined index: acao no momento de enviar dados do ajax para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html5

eu estou tendo problemas para enviar os parâmetros do meu ajax para o PHP, está me dando o erro Undefined index: acao  no meu arquivo logar.php

o meu ajax pega o usuário e a senha do formulário em html e envia para o arquivo logar.php, neste arquivo eu instancio a classe querysDB e chamo a função logar e passo os parâmetros para ela, e depois envio a variável $ok para o meu ajax.

Arquivo logar.php

```
 <?php
 include_once("querysDB.php");
 include_once("bancoDB.php");

 $querys=new querys();
 $acao=$_POST['acao'];

switch ($acao) {
case 'logando':
$usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
$senha= $_POST['senha'];
if(!empty($usuario) && $usuario!='' && !empty($senha) && $usuario!=''){
  echo json_encode($querys->logar($conexcao,$usuario,$senha));
}else{

}
break;

default:
break;
   }
?>
```

arquivo login.js

```
var log = {

init: function(){

},

entrar: function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "logar.php",

     data:{
       acao:'logando',
       usuario: $("#usuario").val(),
       senha:   $("#senha").val()
     },

     dataType: "json",

     success: function(json){
       if(json.result== true){
          alert(json.ok);
       }
     },
     error: function(){
       alert("Erro ao enviar dados");
     }
   });

  }
}
```

Arquivo querysDB.php

```
class querys{

function logar($conexcao,$usuario,$senha){
try {
       $query=mysqli_query($conexcao,"SELECT Nome,Senha FROM usuarios");
       $dados=$query;
       $arrayResultado=array();

while($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($dados)){

     $arrayResultado['nome']=$resultado['Nome'];
     $arrayResultado['Senha']=$resultado['Senha'];

}
 $ok='';
 for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arrayResultado); $i++){

    if($arrayResultado[$i]==$usuario && $arrayResultado[$i]==$senha){

       $ok=true;
    }else{

      $ok=false;
    }
  }
  $dadosjson['result']=true;

  $dadosjson['ok']=$ok;

  return $dadosjson;

   } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;

   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz dois testes, o primeiro:

```
data:{
   acao: "logando", // nota que eu mudei para aspas duplas
   usuario: $("#usuario").val(),
   senha:   $("#senha").val()
 }
```

E o segundo:

```
data:{
   "acao": "logando", // quando uso JSON, sempre aspas duplas
   "usuario": $("#usuario").val(),
   "senha":   $("#senha").val()
 }
```

Comment: opa blz Thiago, estive vendo e o meu arquivo js não está atualizando, ou seja, eu faço as mudanças no meu arquivo salvo estás mudanças, mas depois eu abro o console do meu navegador e abro o meu arquivo.js e vejo que não estão com as modificações que eu fiz. Os meus arquivos estão todos no mesmo diretório. Não sei o que pode ser

Comment: Deu certo Thiago, era isso mesmo coloquei aspas duplas e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

O erro *undefined index* é claro. O índice "acao" não está definido.

Verifique se a variável $_POST['acao'] foi realmente passada para o ajax.

Comment: Então o meu problema está no arquivo js, pois eu deletei ele, mas mesmo assim quando abro a pagina e vou no console ele ainda está la.